# Связать checkbox и элемент списка li ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Пытаюсь повторить вот этот todo проект: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/)

Как можно ГРАМОТНО связать заметку вместе с radio-button, чтобы когда я на него нажимал заметка зачеркивалась. Подскажите react-овское решение вопроса.

Comment: Нам бы на ваш код/наработки взглянуть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант №1:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      crossedOut: false
    }
    
    this.toggleCrossedOut = this.toggleCrossedOut.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleCrossedOut() {
    this.setState({
      crossedOut: !this.state.crossedOut
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { crossedOut } = this.state;
    return (
      <label
        className={crossedOut? "crossed-out": ""}
      >
        Some text
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleCrossedOut} />
      </label>
    )
  }
}
```

Вариант №2 (с использованием npm пакета [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames))

```js
import React from 'react';
import classNames from "classnames";

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      crossedOut: false
    }
    
    this.toggleCrossedOut = this.toggleCrossedOut.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleCrossedOut() {
    this.setState({
      crossedOut: !this.state.crossedOut
    })
  }

  render () {
    const { crossedOut } = this.state;
    return (
      <label
        className={classNames({
          "crossed-out": crossedOut
        })}
      >
        Some text
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleCrossedOut} />
      </label>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот [видео от  Dan Abramov](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-extracting-container-components-visibletodolist-addtodo). Нужно будет зарегистрироваться.
Ниже код, если лень регистрироваться и смотреть.

```js
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      };
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        completed: !state.completed
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return [...state, todo(undefined, action)];
    case "TOGGLE_TODO":
      return state.map(t => todo(t, action));
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = "SHOW_ALL", action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER":
      return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const { combineReducers } = Redux;
const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
});

const { createStore } = Redux;
const store = createStore(todoApp);

const { Component } = React;

const FilterLink = ({
  filter,
  currentFilter,
  children
}) => {
  if (filter === currentFilter) {
    return (
      <span>{children}</span>
    );
  }
  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch({
          type: "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER",
          filter
        });
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case "SHOW_ALL":
      return todos;
    case "SHOW_COMPLETED":
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed);
    case "SHOW_ACTIVE":
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed);
  }
};
let nextTodoId = 0;

class TodoApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      todos,
      visibilityFilter
    } = this.props;
    const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(
      todos,
      visibilityFilter
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          ref={node => {
            this.input = node;
          }}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            store.dispatch({
              type: "ADD_TODO",
              text: this.input.value,
              id: nextTodoId++
            });
            this.input.value = "";
          }}
        >
          Add Todo
        </button>
        <ul>
          {visibleTodos.map(todo => (
            <li
              key={todo.id}
              onClick={() => {
                store.dispatch({
                  type: "TOGGLE_TODO",
                  id: todo.id
                });
              }}
              style={{
                textDecoration: todo.completed ? "line-through" : "none"
              }}
            >
              {todo.text}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <p>
          Show: 
          {'  '} 
          <FilterLink 
             filter="SHOW_ALL"
             currentFilter={visibilityFilter} 
          >
            All
          </FilterLink>
          {'  '} 
          <FilterLink 
             filter="SHOW_COMPLETED"
             currentFilter={visibilityFilter} 
          >
            Completed
          </FilterLink>
          {'  '} 
          <FilterLink 
             filter="SHOW_ACTIVE"
             currentFilter={visibilityFilter} 
          >
            Active
          </FilterLink>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoApp {...store.getState()} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```